# PyDev and Unittesting, not showing time / successful runs in summary?

Tags: pydev, python-unittest

Looking at the documentation for PyDev and it's test integration at [The Pydev Site](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_pyunit.html) the screenshot shows output for each test with how long it took the test to run.  However when I run it only failed tests show in the output, and even then the time it took is empty.  I've tried upping the verbosity in the pyunit testrunner config, but that just gave more output to the system out window, not the PyUnit window.  Anyone know how to fix this?  (This is with the 4/4 PyDev 2.0 release)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]The first top-left button on the PyUnit-view seems to be pressed by default. If you hover over it it says: "If pressed, shows only errors and failures". Klick it to also see successful runs.